# Datetime objects with pandas mean function

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, mean

I am new to programming so I apologize in advance if this question does not make any sens. 
I noticed that when I try to calculate the mean value of a pandas data frame with a date time object formatted like this:  datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 10), it can not calculate the mean value of it however it seems to be able to calculate the minimum and maximum value of that same data frame with out a problem.

```
d={'one' : Series([1, 2, 3], index=['a', 'b', 'c']), 'two' :Series([datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 9) , datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 10) , datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 11) ], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)

df
Out[18]: 
      one        two    
   a    1 2014-07-09
   b    2 2014-07-10
   c    3 2014-07-11

df.min()
Out[19]: 
   one             1
   two    2014-07-09
dtype: object

df.mean()
Out[20]: 
   one    2
dtype: float64
```

I did notice that the min and the max function converted all the columns to objects, where as the mean function only outputs floats. 
Could anyone explain to me why the mean function can only handle floats? 
Is there another way I to get the mean values of a data frame with a date time object? 
I can work around it by using epoch time (as integer), but it would be very convenient if there was a direct way. I use Python 2.7

I am grateful for any hints.

Comment: I don't believe you can (I could be wrong) for instance `np.mean(df['two'])` raises a `TypeError`, converting to ints is probably your best bet, also in case you are thinking about it you can't perform `np.sum` either

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use datetime.timedelta

```
import functools
import operator
import datetime

import pandas as pd

d={'one' : pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=['a', 'b', 'c']), 'two' :pd.Series([datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 9) , datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 10) , datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 11) ], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

def avg_datetime(series):
    dt_min = series.min()
    deltas = [x-dt_min for x in series]
    return dt_min + functools.reduce(operator.add, deltas) / len(deltas)

print(avg_datetime(df['two']))
```

Comment: It looks like a great solution however to my data I get the following error OverflowError: int too big to convert. Is there a good solution to this?

Comment: I, like @S.K., was getting OverflowError when trying to run the above function. I posted the same question and got a better answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358564/computing-the-mean-for-python-datetime/50358798#50358798

Answer (score 14):

To simplify Alex's answer (I would have added this as a comment but I don't have sufficient reputation):

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

d={'one': pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=['a', 'b', 'c']), 
   'two': pd.Series([datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 9), 
           datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 10), 
           datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 11) ], 
           index=['a', 'b', 'c'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Which looks like:

```
   one   two
a   1   2014-07-09
b   2   2014-07-10
c   3   2014-07-11
```

Then calculate the mean of column "two" by:

```
(df.two - df.two.min()).mean() + df.two.min()
```

So, subtract the min of the timeseries, calculate the mean (or median) of the resulting timedeltas, and add back the min.

Answer (score 6):

This issue is sort of resolved as of pandas=0.25.  However mean can only currently be applied to a datetime series and not a datetime series within a DataFrame.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: s = pd.Series([pd.datetime(2014, 7, 9), 
   ...:            pd.datetime(2014, 7, 10), 
   ...:            pd.datetime(2014, 7, 11)])

In [3]: s.mean()
Out[3]: Timestamp('2014-07-10 00:00:00')
```

Applying .mean() to a DataFrame containing a datetime series returns the same result as shown in the original question.

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'numeric':[1,2,3],
   ...:               'datetime':s})

In [5]: df.mean()
Out[5]: 
numeric    2.0
dtype: float64
```