# computing the mean for python datetime

Tags: python, pandas, mean, python-datetime

I have a datetime attribute:

```
d = {
    'DOB': pd.Series([
        datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 9),
        datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 15),
        np.datetime64('NaT')
    ], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I would like to compute the mean for that attribute. Running mean() causes an error:

> TypeError: reduction operation 'mean' not allowed for this dtype

I also tried the solution proposed [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907902/datetime-objects-with-pandas-mean-function). It doesn't work as running the function proposed there causes

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

What would you propose? The result for the above dataframe should be equivalent to

```
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 12).
```

Comment: You can use `.totimestamp()` to convert the `datetime`-values to continuous float values, compute the mean of that and convert the result via `datetime.fromtimestamp()`. Remember that you can get weird calendar-effects due due to lapse-seconds, -days, -whatever.

Comment: @user2722968 Would you write a working solution? I'd be happy to accept it - if it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datetime objects with pandas mean function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907902/datetime-objects-with-pandas-mean-function)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can take the mean of `Timedelta`.  So find the minimum value and subtract it from the series to get a series of `Timedelta`.  Then take the mean and add it back to the minimum.

```
dob = df_test.DOB
m = dob.min()
(m + (dob - m).mean()).to_pydatetime()

datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 12, 0, 0)
```

---

One-line

```
df_test.DOB.pipe(lambda d: (lambda m: m + (d - m).mean())(d.min())).to_pydatetime()
```

---

To [@ALollz point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358564/computing-the-mean-for-python-datetime/50358798#comment87734565_50358798)

I use the epoch `pd.Timestamp(0)` instead of `min`

```
df_test.DOB.pipe(lambda d: (lambda m: m + (d - m).mean())(pd.Timestamp(0))).to_pydatetime()
```

Comment: Thanks! For completeness sake can you, perhaps, add a transformation from a Timestamp into datetime?

Comment: Does it even need to be the minimum or can you just subtract off some arbitrary date and just add that back later?

Comment: @ALollz you are correct.  But the minimum is an easy guarantee.  Supposing I subtracted the epoch... it would seem very similar to your answer.

Comment: Yeah I just realized the similarly! I agree the minimum is a nice guarantee. +1

Answer (score 5):

You can convert epoch time using `astype` with np.int64 and converting back to datetime with `pd.to_datetime`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df_test.DOB.dropna().astype(np.int64).mean())
```

Output:

```
Timestamp('2014-07-12 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 3):

Datetime math supports some standard operations:

```
a = datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 9)
b = datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 15)
c = (b - a)/2

# here c will be datetime.timedelta(3)

a + c
Out[7]: datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 12, 0, 0)
```

So you can write a function that, given two datetimes, subtracts the lesser form the greater and adds half of the difference to the lesser. Apply this function to your dataframe, and shazam!

Comment: This is the most elegant solution. Does not require pandas or any third party dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You could work with `unix` time if you want. This is defined as the total number of seconds (for instance) since `1970-01-01`. With that, all of your times are simply floats, so it's very easy to do simple math on the columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df_test['unix_time'] = (df_test.DOB - pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01')).dt.total_seconds()

df_test['unix_time'].mean()
#1405123200.0

# You want it in date, so just convert back
pd.to_datetime(df_test['unix_time'].mean(), origin='unix', unit='s')
#Timestamp('2014-07-12 00:00:00')
```

Comment: The trouble is that I want a generic solution. I have dates that precede 1970-01-01 - I just did not show them above.

Comment: @Nick I don't see the issue. There are certainly negative numbers, so you can have negative `unix` time.

Comment: For instance add `datetime.datetime(1800, 7, 9)` to your `df` Nothing wrong happens.

Answer (score 1):

As of pandas=0.25, it is possible to compute the mean of a datetime series.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: import numpy as np

In [2]: s = pd.Series([
   ...:     pd.datetime(2014, 7, 9),
   ...:     pd.datetime(2014, 7, 15),
   ...:     np.datetime64('NaT')])

In [3]: s.mean()
Out[3]: Timestamp('2014-07-12 00:00:00')
```

However, note that applying mean to a pandas dataframe currently ignores columns with a datetime series.