# How to calculate the mean of multiple Python Pandas datetime64[ns] values per row of the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
MC_schedule_df: 

    Act_Arr_Run-0        Act_Arr_Run-1          Act_Arr_Run-2        Act_Arr_Run-3
0   2005-08-05 05:15:08  2005-08-05 05:12:00    2005-08-05 05:16:50  2005-08-05 05:09:13
1   2005-08-05 06:18:30  2005-08-05 06:14:50    2005-08-05 06:14:29  2005-08-05 06:07:31
2   2005-08-05 06:22:17  2005-08-05 06:18:06    2005-08-05 06:26:25  2005-08-05 06:22:49
3   2005-08-05 08:52:56  2005-08-05 08:58:51    2005-08-05 09:05:27  2005-08-05 08:58:43
4   2005-08-05 13:04:24  2005-08-05 12:58:11    2005-08-05 13:05:41  2005-08-05 13:02:33
5   2005-08-05 13:22:08  2005-08-05 13:14:44    2005-08-05 13:09:08  2005-08-05 13:12:27
6   2005-08-05 14:26:38  2005-08-05 14:13:38    2005-08-05 14:17:31  2005-08-05 14:17:33
7   2005-08-05 18:08:41  2005-08-05 18:17:15    2005-08-05 18:14:21  2005-08-05 18:15:54
8   2005-08-05 19:46:15  2005-08-05 19:45:28    2005-08-05 19:46:20  2005-08-05 19:48:44
9   2005-08-05 23:13:53  2005-08-05 23:06:06    2005-08-05 23:06:25  2005-08-05 23:04:07
```

Hello,

I have the dataframe (MC_schedule_df) shown above, consisting of the following datatypes:

```
In[1]: MC_schedule_df.dtypes
Out[1]: 
Act_Arr_Run-0    datetime64[ns]
Act_Arr_Run-1    datetime64[ns]
Act_Arr_Run-2    datetime64[ns]
Act_Arr_Run-3    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

The dataframe consists of rows of datetime values, of which i want to calculate the mean per row. I have tried the following code:

```
MC_schedule_df = MC_schedule_df.assign(Average=MC_schedule_df.mean(axis=1))
```

This results in a column filled with NaN values. I have tried to find out why this does not work and thus have read loads of documentation. My current guess is that Python is not able to 'destilate' the appropriate information from the datetime values to calculate the mean.

How to calculate the mean of these multiple Python Pandas datetime64[ns] values? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: i tried the methods of [Datetime objects with pandas mean function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907902/datetime-objects-with-pandas-mean-function). However, this method does not work, as i want to calculate the mean per row, and thus can not easily call the series.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datetime objects with pandas mean function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907902/datetime-objects-with-pandas-mean-function)

Comment: i tried the methods of your link  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907902/datetime-objects-with-pandas-mean-function). However, this method does not work, as i want to calculate the mean per row, and thus can not easily call the series.

Comment: Yes, you need to use that technique on each row. You can do it using `apply`. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use what shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47293691/10426037). As pointed out in the link, you cannot calculate the mean of a bunch of dates, the operation is not supported. But you can calculate the average of a bunch of timedeltas.
Use the [pandas apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function to generalize it and apply it to a DataFrame instead of a Series.

```
mean_values = MC_schedule_df.apply(lambda dt : (dt - dt.min()).mean() + dt.min(), axis=1)
```

Using your sample dataframe, `mean_values` is:

```
0   2005-08-05 05:13:17.750
1   2005-08-05 06:13:50.000
2   2005-08-05 06:22:24.250
3   2005-08-05 08:58:59.250
4   2005-08-05 13:02:42.250
5   2005-08-05 13:14:36.750
6   2005-08-05 14:18:50.000
7   2005-08-05 18:14:02.750
8   2005-08-05 19:46:41.750
9   2005-08-05 23:07:37.750
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```