# Why does pandas mean, on datetime, work on a series but not on a groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, mean

I am trying to take the mean of dates in by groups.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Date': [pd.datetime(2000, 12, 31), pd.datetime(2002, 12, 31),
                            pd.datetime(2000, 6, 30), pd.datetime(2002, 6, 30)]})
```

This has always been a pain to do, so I was pleased to learn that this had apparntly been fixed in pandas 0.25 [Datetime objects with pandas mean function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907902/datetime-objects-with-pandas-mean-function).

```
df['Date'].mean()
Out[45]: Timestamp('2001-09-30 00:00:00') # This works
```

However, this cant be done using ´groupby´

```
df.groupby('Id')['Date'].mean()

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-46-5fae5ffac6c6>", line 1, in <module>
    df.groupby('Id')['Date'].mean()

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 1205, in mean
"mean", alt=lambda x, axis: Series(x).mean(**kwargs), **kwargs

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 888, in _cython_agg_general
raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

What is going on here, and is there an easy workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambda function with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) or [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
print (df.groupby('Id')['Date'].agg(lambda x: x.mean()))
print (df.groupby('Id')['Date'].agg(pd.Series.mean))
print (df.groupby('Id')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.mean()))
print (df.groupby('Id')['Date'].apply(pd.Series.mean))

Id
A   2001-12-31
B   2001-06-30
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Difference is if multiple columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Date': [pd.datetime(2000, 12, 31), pd.datetime(2002, 12, 31),
                            pd.datetime(2000, 6, 30), pd.datetime(2002, 6, 30)]})
df['Date1'] = df['Date']
print (df.groupby('Id').agg(lambda x: x.mean()))
         Date      Date1
Id                      
A  2001-12-31 2001-12-31
B  2001-06-30 2001-06-30
print (df.groupby('Id').agg(pd.Series.mean))
         Date      Date1
Id                      
A  2001-12-31 2001-12-31
B  2001-06-30 2001-06-30

print (df.groupby('Id').apply(lambda x: x.mean()))
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

print (df.groupby('Id').apply(pd.Series.mean))
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

> Why does pandas mean, on datetime, work on a series but not on a groupby object

Some time ago it was problem with `mean` for Series, Datetimes, check [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/24757), so possible in some next versions of pandas this should working well.

Comment: Ok. Hehe. Easy. Why tough? Do I have to use ´apply´?