# Mean of every 15 rows of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, mean

I have a dataframe of (1500x11). I have to select each of the 15 rows and take mean of every 11 columns separately. So my final dataframe should be of dimension 100x11. How to do this in Python.

Comment: i think this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810595/calculate-average-of-every-x-rows-in-a-table-and-create-new-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
dfnew=df[:0]
for i in range(100):
    df2=df.iloc[i*15:i*15+15, :]
    x=pd.Series(dict(df2.mean()))
    dfnew=dfnew.append(x, ignore_index=True)

print(dfnew)
```

Comment: One column of my dataframe is Datetime. How to get its mean. The above method displays it as "NaT".  TIME
2020-04-01 06:01:00
2020-04-01 06:02:00
2020-04-01 06:03:00
2020-04-01 06:04:00
....................................... TIME
2020-04-02 17:42:00
2020-04-02 17:43:00
2020-04-02 17:44:00
2020-04-02 17:45:00
2020-04-02 17:46:00

Comment: Take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907902/datetime-objects-with-pandas-mean-function

Answer (score 1):

Don't know much about `pandas`, hence I've coded my next solution in pure `numpy`. Without any python loops hence very efficient. And converted result back to `pandas` `DataFrame`:

[Try next code online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64059897#main.py)

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[i + j for j in range(11)] for i in range(1500)])
a = df.values
a = a.reshape((a.shape[0] // 15, 15, a.shape[1]))
a = np.mean(a, axis = 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas.DataFrame.

Use a for loop to compute the means and create a counter which should be reseted at every 15 entries.

```
columns = [col1, col2, ..., col12]
for columns, values in df.items():
    # compute mean
    # at every 15 entries save it
```

Also, using pd.DataFrame() you can create the new dataframe.

I'd recommend you to read the documentation.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html