# How do I convert time from being an object to an integer in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert a column from a large dataset that has the value of time as an object to an integer.

I would like to convert "Duration", "Talk Time" to int so I can perform some basic math such as the mean, the maximum and the minimum time recorded in the dataset.

|  | Duration | Talk Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 00:00:27 | 00:00:26 |
| 1 | 00:00:58 | 00:00:58 |
| 2 | 00:00:48 | 00:00:46 |
| 3 | 00:00:38 | 00:00:38 |
| 4 | 00:00:11 | 00:00:11 |

```js
df['Duration'].astype(np.int64)
```

I get the error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '00:00:27'

Comment: "The current time is display as 00:01:56." What integer do you want to get if you convert that time, and why? According to what logic?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54312802/pandas-convert-from-datetime-to-integer-timestamp answer the question?

Comment: I would like to get the average time and some other calculations but I cannot do that because it's formatted as an object.

Comment: Thank you for the help Karl but that question does not answer my problem since I am not interested in dates. I am only interested about the time.

Comment: What does "average time" mean? What should the "average" of noon and midnight be - 6pm? 6am? something else?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907902/datetime-objects-with-pandas-mean-function answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to convert to seconds (and that is HH:MM:SS representation) and that is always an 8 digit string, the fastest way would be:

<strike>df['dur_in_secs'] = int(df['duration'][0:2])*3600 + int(df['duration'][3:5])*60 + int(df['duration'][6:8])</strike>

if it is not, try to isolate each part with

```
 s_idx = df['duration'].rfind(':') # index to last part
 sec = int(df['duration'][s_idx+1:])
```

etc

Sorry about that, trying to be clever :-(

this has been tested

```
df["secs"] = df["duration"].apply(lambda x:int(x[0:2])*3600+ int(x[3:5])*60 + int(x[6:8]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that code and I got this error:

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable